# Автоматическое обновление страницы после добавления новой записи в БД

Tags: wpf, combobox

Здравствуйте!

У меня страничное приложение для работы с БД. На каждой странице есть `DataGrid`, заполненный данными с заданных таблиц БД. На странице есть кнопка "Добавить", после нажатия на которую сверху страницы появляется окно для внесения данных.
Пользователь заполняет его поля и нажимает кнопку "Сохранить". После этого, чтобы увидеть новую запись в `DataGrid` нужно обновить страницу (Refresh_Click) или просто открыть заново.

Как сделать, чтобы после нажатия кнопки "Добавить" в окне добавления или же закрытия этого окна (что лучше), содержимое странички обновлялось автоматически?

Страничка, которая должна обновляться:

```
public partial class Page1 : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Page
{
    FCEntities2 context = new FCEntities2();
    string filter;

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();           
    }

    //добавление новой записи, вызов окна
    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AdressAdd ad = new AdressAdd(); 
        ad.Show(); 
    }

    private void Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh(); 
    }

    //обновление содержимого окна
    public void Refresh()
    { 
        List<Adress> T = new List<Adress>();
        Adress p = new Adress();
        DataGridAdress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        var query =
            from some in context.Адреса
            orderby some.Адрес
            select new
            {
                idАдреса = some.idАдреса,
                Адрес = some.Адрес,
                НасПункт = some.НасПункт,
            };

        Adress pers;
        foreach (var d in query)
        {
            pers = new Adress();
            pers.idАдреса = d.idАдреса;
            pers.Адрес = d.Адрес;
            pers.НасПункт = d.НасПункт;
            T.Add(pers);
        }

        DataGridAdress.ItemsSource = T;

    }      

    //поиск записи
    private void ShowAdress(String filter = null)
    { 
        using (FCEntities2 context = new FCEntities2())
        {
            List<Adress> T = new List<Adress>();
            Adress p = new Adress();
            DataGridAdress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            var query =
                from some in context.Адреса
                orderby some.Адресc
                select new
                {
                    idАдреса = some.idАдреса,
                    Адрес = some.Адрес,
                    НасПункт = some.НасПункт,
                };
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
            {
                string f = Convert.ToString(filter);
                query = query.Where(c => c.Адрес.Contains(f));
                Adress pers;
                foreach (var d in query)
                {
                    pers = new Adress();                        
                    pers.idАдреса = d.idАдреса;
                    pers.Адрес = d.Адрес;
                    pers.НасПункт = d.НасПункт;
                    T.Add(pers);
                    T.Add(pers);
                }

                DataGridAdress.ItemsSource = T; 
            }
        }
    }

    private void Find_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        filter = Search.Text;
        ShowAdress(filter);
    }
}
```

окно добавления новой записи:

```
public partial class AdressAdd : MetroWindow
{       
    FCEntities2 context = new FCEntities2();
    public AdressAdd()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 

    private void New_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        try
        {                
            Адреса cl = new Адреса();
            cl.Адрес = a.Text;
            cl.НасПункт = b.Text;
            context.Адреса.Add(cl);
            context.SaveChanges();
            a.Clear();
            b.Clear(); 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка!");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызовите **Refresh()** после открытия окна в котором вы добавляете данные. Используйте **ShowDialog()** вместо **Show()**. Так же желательно указать родителя для вашего окна (Owner = this).

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)// добавление новой записи, вызов окна
{
    AdressAdd ad = new AdressAdd();

    ad.Owner = this;

    ad.ShowDialog();

    Refresh();
}
```